# Replace multiple characters in a string using a set of rules

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Rules in applyRules is going to be asked to users, but it does not work what it should work which is `[“character1:substitution”, “character2:substitution”]`

When user put `['b:c','c:d']`, it prints `c,c`. However, it should print `d` when char is `b`

The function takes a single character and a set of rules as a list.

And this is what I wrote so far

```
def applyRules(char, rules):
    for rule_list in (rule.split(':') for rule in rules):
        char = char.replace(rule_list[0], rule_list[1])
    return char
```

What should I add to make it work appropriately?

Comment: Is it a single character substitution?

Comment: you should provide an example *input* to the function and show what the output is vs. what is it you expected it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple rules, this becomes cumbersome. As long as your replacements are done on single characters, you can make this easy with `str.translate`. That, however, doesn't solve the problem of chained replacements, so you'll have to make use of a `while` loop that runs until there are no more changes.

```
def applyRules(string, rules):
    mapping = str.maketrans(dict(x.split(':') for x in rules))

    while True:
        new = string.translate(mapping)
        if string == new:
            break
        string = new

    return new
```

---

```
In [1308]: applyRules('bbbbb', ['b:c', 'c:d'])
Out[1308]: 'ddddd'
```

---

**Single Character Replacement**
For replacement involving a single character, the solution simplifies. You could use a dictionary with `get`:

```
def applyRules(char, rules):
    mapping = dict(x.split(':') for x in rules)

    while True:
        new = mapping.get(char, char)
        if char == new:
            break
        char = new

    return new
```

This should be much simpler.

Comment: @Whitepub This should still work, but you'd see speed gains vs other answers only for strings.

Comment: It works when I write rules in function, but when I ask user like 
`char = input("What character do you want to put?")
    rules = input("Put your rule")
    inst = lsystems.applyRules(char, [rules])
    print(inst)`

It looks like it is not working. How users are supposed to put rules through Python Shell?

Comment: @Whitepub That's an entirely different problem. Ask the input space separated rules like this: `"a:b b:c c:d"` and then pass `rules.split()` to your function.

Comment: @Whitepub Also, see edit. I've added a solution which should be _much cheaper_ than translate for a single character.

Comment: I am sorry, since I am new to coding, it is hard for me to understand quickly. How do I ask the input to separate rules and how to pass rules.split()?

Comment: @Whitepub Ah, just saw this comment now. My apologies. Anyway, I hope my answer to your other question explains what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply each and every rule and also, preserve the new string at the same time since strings are immutable in python. You can use [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) of `str` class. Following code works

```
def applyRules(char, rules):
    modified = char

    for rule in rules:
        r = rule.split(':')
        table = str.maketrans({r[0]:r[1]})
        modified = modified.translate(table)

    return modified

print(applyRules('bbbbb',['b:c','c:d'])) #prints 'ddddd'
print(applyRules('abdecbc',['b:c','c:d'])) #prints 'addeddd'
```

Comment: If you replace only one character at a time, you end up with O(n^2) complexity. If you perform replacement with all the rules together (inside a condition controlled while), you end up with something a lot faster.