# Python ApplyRules() Function for Lsystem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that takes a single character and a set of rules as a list.

The format of the rules list will be a set of strings in this format: [“character1:substitution”, “character2:substitution”]

I need to loop through the rules list, and parse the strings into symbol and substitutions.

I should use the number of rules to loop n times, and ask the user to input the rule in the specified format, “character:substitution”. And store each rule string in a combined list.

This is code I wrote so far:

```
def applyRules(char, rules):
    for rule_list in (rule.split(':') for rule in rules):
        char = char.replace(rule_list[0], rule_list[1])
    return char
```

---

```
import lsystems
import turtle

def main():
    char = input("What character do you want to put?")
    rules = input("Put your rule")
    inst = lsystems.applyRules(char, rules)
    print(inst)


Input char b

Input rule b:c c:d
```

It should print d, however, it gives me error all times I try unless I put only one rule such as b:c.

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

**File "C:\Users\wpw\Desktop\csp\mainmodule.py", line 13, in  main()**

**File "C:\Users\wpw\Desktop\csp\mainmodule.py", line 7, in main**
    **inst = lsystems.applyRules(char, rules)**

**File "C:\Users\wpw\Desktop\cs110\lsystemfunctions.py", line 5, in applyRules**
    **char = char.replace(rule_list[0], rule_list[1])**

**IndexError: list index out of range**

What should I do to print output right?

Comment: Did you take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46901612/4909087 - **Single Character Replacement** code?

Comment: Furthermore, you are passing `rules` to the function when you should be passing `rules.split()`, I showed you how to from your previous question.

Comment: I did see the function for the single character replacement code, but since I did not learn dict.() and get() I don't think I can use the functions. I tried to use `rules.split` but it seems not working though I put it in.. **It says split() cannot be used for list**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need to use `.split()` to convert your rules string into a rules list:

```
def applyRules(string, rules):
    for character, substitution in (rule.split(':') for rule in rules):
        string = string.replace(character, substitution)
    return string

def main():
    char = input("What character do you want to put? ")
    rules = input("Put your rules: ").split()
    inst = applyRules(char, rules)
    print(inst)

main()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
What character do you want to put? b
Put your rules: b:c c:d
d
%
```

This assumes your rules are in a single input separated by white space.  Another approach would be to put `input("Put your rules: ")` into loop, appending to `rules` as you input individual rules from the user, with an empty response signaling the end of rule input.

Comment: Thank you for help!